# how can i keep the value when save and confirm? odoo v 8.0

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

this method return product quantity(`qty_available`) of related `product_id`, it's working fine, the problem is when save or confirm action I get the default value of `qty_available`.

```
 def onchange_product_id(self, cr, uid, ids, product_id=False, product_uom_qty=0.0, product_uom=False, price_unit=0.0, qty_available=0.0, virtual_available=0.0, name='', analytic_account_id=False, context=None):
    result = {}
    product_obj = self.pool.get('product.product')
    if not product_id:
        return {'value': {'product_uom_qty': 1.0, 'product_uom': False, 'price_unit': 0.0, 'qty_available': 0.0, 'virtual_available': 0.0, 'name': '', 'delay': 0.0}}

    product = product_obj.browse(cr, uid, product_id, context=context)

    result['name'] = product_obj.name_get(cr, uid, [product.id])[0][1]
    result['product_uom'] = product.uom_id.id
    result['qty_available'] = product.qty_available

    return {'value': result}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code which is converted in new API Odoo V8:

```python
@api.onchange('product_id', 'product_id.uom_id', 'product_id.qty_available')
def onchange_product_id(self):

    if not self.product_id:
        self.product_uom_qty = 1.0
        self.product_uom = False
        self.price_unit = 0.0
        self.qty_available = 0.0
        self.virtual_available = 0.0
        self.name = ''
        self.delay = 0.0

    self.name = self.product_id.name
    self.product_uom = self.product_id.uom_id
    self.qty_available = self.product_id.qty_available
```

Comment: i tried this, but how to call it in xml file with on_change, so i got this error :
TypeError: onchange_product_id() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)

Comment: @moo you onchange fields is define  in api.onchange('filed name') and remove in on_change in xml file. your code worked..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```python
def onchange_product_id(self, cr, uid, ids, product_id=False, product_uom_qty=0.0, product_uom=False, price_unit=0.0, qty_available=0.0, virtual_available=0.0, name='', analytic_account_id=False, context=None):

    result = {}
    product_obj = self.pool.get('product.product')
    if not product_id:
        return {'value': {'product_uom_qty': 1.0, 'product_uom': False, 'price_unit': 0.0, 'qty_available': 0.0, 'virtual_available': 0.0, 'name': '', 'delay': 0.0}}

    product = product_obj.browse(cr, uid, product_id, context=context)

    res['value'].update({'name': product_obj.name_get(cr, uid, [product.id])[0][1], 'product_uom': product.uom_id.id, 'qty_available': product.qty_available})
    return res
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit?

Comment: I  think if you update dict , your problem may be solved

Comment: thanks RaviPatel, when update dict, I got Keyerror' value..i think the problem with readonly attribute of qty_available, it's work fine when I set it to False